# `fly deploy` fails to deploy Rails 7 app with "Missing encryption key to decrypt file with." when rails master key is present on Fly.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-7, fly

I'm trying to evaluate Fly.io and deploy an existing Rails 7 app. Following their guide for [existing rails apps](https://fly.io/docs/rails/getting-started/existing/#access-to-environment-variables-at-build-time), `fly launch` works fine, however `fly deploy` fails on the `assets:precompile` step.

Console Ouput:

```
 => [build 5/6] RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/                                                                                                                                      1.1s 
 => ERROR [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile                                                                                                                    2.1s
------
 > [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
#16 2.043 Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /rails/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
------
Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile]: exit code: 1
```

Obviously, this is a common enough problem that it’s mentioned in Fly's [Getting Started Guide](https://fly.io/docs/rails/getting-started/existing/#access-to-environment-variables-at-build-time)

I have my Rails master key in the correct config file (config/master.key), and the error output even links to the file.
Fly launch successfully created the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable and I’ve confirmed that the key is correct.
My `secret_key_base` is in the rails credentials file.

I've tried setting the Dockerfile to both of these:

```
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
```

Both result in the same error

There's also [this issue on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947), but the solution to that seems to be the dummy secret key base.

Any suggestions for what to try in order to resolve this?

Comment: The error appears to be related to the `sassc-rails` gem. Deploys work with `cssbundling-rails` but fail with `sassc-rails` and `dartsass-rails`

Comment: The `SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY` method will be available once rails 7.1 is out.

Comment: @Phil-6 I've had this issue for weeks, and I don't have sass-rails in my gemfile, and I ended up (for now) just turning off require master key. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

I have now managed to get this to work although it's not an ideal solution.

I've updating the Dockerfile to manually add an ARG and ENV var for the RAILS_MASTER_KEY and then passing the key value as a build arg.

Dockerfile

```
ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY
# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    RAILS_MASTER_KEY=${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
```

Testing locally if you have docker installed:

```
sudo docker compose build --build-arg RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/master.key)
```

Deploying to Fly.io:

```
fly deploy --build-arg RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/master.key)
```

Comment: you should select this as an correct asnwer because fly io solution also passing hte master key as build arg in fly deploy

Answer (score 0):

I fall into the same issue. The solution was found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947 user *alphabt*:

> is basically a build step. Should we really need the master key during precompile? I had to perform wacky workaround by injecting dummy key into my CI build (because I don't want to expose my real key during build) to get around this issue 
> Workaround in Dockerfile

```
# Precompile assets
# We use dummy master.key and credentials.yml.enc to workaround the fact that
# assets:precompile needs them but we don't want the real master.key to be built
# into the container. We will inject RAILS_MASTER_KEY env var when starting the
# container.

RUN if [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "production" ]]; then \
  mv config/credentials.yml.enc config/credentials.yml.enc.backup; \
  mv config/credentials.yml.enc.sample config/credentials.yml.enc; \
  mv config/master.key.sample config/master.key; \
  bundle exec rails assets:precompile; \
  mv config/credentials.yml.enc.backup config/credentials.yml.enc; \
  rm config/master.key; \
fi
```

This helped me to solve the problem.
Also I think it worth to note that Rails app may demands more than 256Mb of RAM if you run it in a free tier. When I tried to deploy my app I got a message: "*Hello! Your “veselka” application hosted on Fly.io crashed because it ran out of memory. Specifically, the instance 1781991ae3e028. Adding more RAM to your application might help!*". So I've increased the RAM size to 512M. Now app's runing well.